# Fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file?

Tags: vb6

"Spontaneously" our VB6 build has started failing with the following error in one project out of several:

> Unexpected error occurred in code generator or linker.
> fatal error
> C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file:
> 'D:\path\to\file\frmSomeForm.OBJ': No such file or directory

The form in question is not a new addition and hasn't even been modified.

The PC is not out of disk space or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that another developer changed the `Path32` line in the project's VBP file to a local path **which does not exist on the build machine.** Changing it back to the correct value (which is supposed to be a relative path) resolved the issue.

It might also be relevant that the nonexistent path was on a nonexisting drive. (There was no `D:` drive though the path used this).

---

(Surprisingly, I couldn't find another example of this in the web so I've added it here... I wanted to look up any official specification for  `Path32` but I can't find it in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/visual-basic-6.0-documentation or anywhere else.)